# How to translate the object c into rubymotion to fetch facebook user’s information

Tags: rubymotion

I tried  to translate part of the objective-c but I still stuck at part of them

any idea ? Thanks so much

## objective c version

> if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
>         NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture",@"fields",nil];
>         FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
>                                       initWithGraphPath:@"me"
>                                       parameters:params
>                                       HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
>         [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
>                                               id result,
>                                               NSError *error) {
>             UIImage * downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pictureData];
>             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>                 self.profilePictureImageView.image = downloadedImage;
>             });
>
> ```
>   }];
> ```
>
> }

## ruby motion version

> if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken) {
>
> ```
> request = FBSDKGraphRequest.alloc.initWithGraphPath("me", parameters:nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with the corresponding code in rubymotion

Please correct me directly if anything wrong, it works for me now

## part of original objective-c

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
       FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                     initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
       [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                             id result,
                                             NSError *error) {
       }];
   }
```

## convert version by ruby_motion_query

```
def loginButton(loginButton, didCompleteWithResult: result, error: error)
  puts result
  puts error
  if not error
      request = FBSDKGraphRequest.alloc.initWithGraphPath("me", parameters:nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
      request.startWithCompletionHandler( lambda{ |connection, user, error|
          #DO_ANYTHING_YOU_WANT_FATE_LOGINING_SUCESSFULLY
          rmq(@fb_login_button).animate { |btn| btn.move(b: 400) }

          @name_label = rmq.append(UILabel, :label_name).get
          @name_label.text = "#{user['first_name']} #{user['last_name']}"
          rmq(@name_label).animations.fade_in
      })
  end
end

def loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton)
  #DO_ANYTHING_YOU_WANT_HERE
end
```